# Android renewed subscription orderID

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

The 'recurrence orderID' given by `inventory.getPurchase` doesn't have "..X' as suffix in it.
But According to Google's docs the recurrence orderID should have '..X' as a suffix. Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone please let me know if we actually get the recurrence orderID as mentioned in Google's docs? (I have added for monthly subscription).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The 'X' suffix they mention does not mean literally the letter 'X'. It stands for a number that they append - 1, 2, 3, etc.

You can find more info about this in Google's 'Subscription order numbers' documentation under [Payment Processing and Policies](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#payment).

Comment: That i understand....but i was not able to get recurrence orderID with  any of those suffix...So i just wanted to know if they do provide those orderID...JFYI i was getting the proper recurrence orderID in the order confirmation email.